# SQL statement group? or sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

im new to SQL so looking for some assistance.
heres my code

```
Select
    MITARBEITER_NR "ID",
   DAUER "Duration",
datum "Date"
From
Vtsbreak 
Where DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/04/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/27','yyyy/mm/dd') 
order by datum
```

this is my data

```
ID  Duration    Date
443 60  03/04/2017
412 10  03/04/2017
399 100 04/04/2017
374 10  04/04/2017
374 10  04/04/2017
376 120 04/04/2017
456 300 04/04/2017
372 120 04/04/2017
443 60  04/04/2017
446 300 04/04/2017
427 60  04/04/2017
403 420 04/04/2017
```

what I am trying to do is return the ID code, Date, sum of duration for that date
I have tried using group but just returns one case of id 374 for 04/04/2017 with a value of 10 instead of 20

any suggestions please?

Comment: Your syntax is not MySQL syntax.  Are you getting an error?  Should the tag be Oracle?  Postgres?  Teradata?

Comment: You say you "have tried using group"... Not in the query you show. *Show your **actual** work!*

Answer (score 1):

You want a `GROUP BY`.  Following the syntax you are using (but definitely not MySQL), you can do something like this:

```
select MITARBEITER_NR as id,
       to_char(datum, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as yyyymmdd,
       sum(dauer) as duration
from Vtsbreak 
where datum >= DATE '2017-04-01' and
      datum < DATE '2017-05-28'
group by id, to_char(datum, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by yyyymmdd;
```

Comment: Missing `ORDER BY` :)

Comment: Sorry I think it might be oracle.

Comment: with the above statement I get :ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @alejandrogiron Only if ordering is important. ;) If ordering is not important, then order by is just wasteful. And question is not clear whether ordering is important for the answer.

Comment: @CraigYoung Yep, just said it because the OP original query had the `ORDER BY datum` at the end

Answer (score 0):

sorted it

```
Select
    MITARBEITER_NR "ID",
   sum(DAUER) "Duration",
   datum "Date"
From
Vtsbreak 
Where DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/04/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/27','yyyy/mm/dd') 
group by MITARBEITER_NR, datum;
order by datum
```